# Unable To Install 'therubyracer v0.12.3' gem in M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos-big-sur, therubyracer, apple-m1, libv8

I am using M1 Macbook Pro and wants to install therubyracer and libv8 for a rails webapp. But I am unable to do so because of the errors described below. There are several solutions available on the internet but none of them is working for me.

Operating System: `macOS Big Sur v11.1`.

It would be very helpful if someone can help me with this.

Log:

```sh
❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [-darwin20]
❯ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.17.3
❯ brew -v
Homebrew 2.7.5
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision e04a30; last commit 2021-01-20)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision d128de; last commit 2021-01-20)
❯ uname -a
Darwin Vaibhavs-MacBook-Pro.local 20.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.2.0: Wed Dec  2 20:40:21 PST 2020; root:xnu-7195.60.75~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64


❯ brew search v8
==> Formulae
v8 ✔                                                                 v8@3.15
==> Casks
amitv87-pip


❯ brew install v8@3.15
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 3 formulae.
==> Updated Casks
Updated 3 casks.

Error: v8@3.15: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source v8@3.15
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.


❯ brew install --build-from-source v8@3.15
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 1 cask.

==> Cloning https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp.git
Updating /Users/vaibhavgupta/Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8@3.15--gyp--git
==> Checking out revision f7bc250ccc4d619a1cf238db87e5979f89ff36d7
HEAD is now at f7bc250c Make gyp/win32 compatible with upstream ninja.
HEAD is now at f7bc250c Make gyp/win32 compatible with upstream ninja.
==> Downloading https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/archive/3.15.11.18.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/vaibhavgupta/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/26ea05158c6c6ebb67cc42075858df9a986f9c615513933b1e62bb707f707854--v8-3.15.11.18.tar.gz
==> make native -j8 library=shared snapshot=on console=readline
Last 15 lines from /Users/vaibhavgupta/Library/Logs/Homebrew/v8@3.15/01.make:
Atomic32 Acquire_Load(volatile const Atomic32* ptr);
         ^
In file included from ../src/conversions.cc:32:
In file included from ../src/conversions-inl.h:42:
In file included from ../src/platform.h:100:
In file included from ../src/lazy-instance.h:94:
../src/once.h:115:7: error: no matching function for call to 'Acquire_Load'
  if (Acquire_Load(once) != ONCE_STATE_DONE) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/atomicops.h:125:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::internal::OnceType *' (aka 'long *') to 'const volatile v8::internal::Atomic32 *' (aka 'const volatile int *') for 1st argument
Atomic32 Acquire_Load(volatile const Atomic32* ptr);
         ^
5 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [/private/tmp/v8-3.15-20210120-4211-1soh8ig/v8-3.15.11.18/out/native/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o] Error 1
make: *** [native] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


❯ brew install v8
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/v8-8.8.278.14.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/vaibhavgupta/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/457adba5b4da5d7cb7d6d896218ebc5d8f1453782321e97a3df424f4a4e8a821--v8-8.8.278.14.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring v8-8.8.278.14.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/v8/8.8.278.14: 80 files, 39.9MB


❯ brew --prefix v8
/opt/homebrew/opt/v8


❯ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19'
Fetching libv8-3.16.14.19.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20210120-6051-11xeqcl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-building-tests.patch
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-werror-on-osx.patch
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-xcode-debugging.patch
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-imply-vfp3-and-armv7.patch
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-use-MAP_NORESERVE-on-freebsd.patch
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-use-vfp2.patch
Applying /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/fPIC-for-static.patch
Compiling v8 for arm
Using python 2.7.16
Using compiler: c++ (clang version 12.0.0)
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Beginning compilation. This will take some time.
Building v8 with env CXX=c++ LINK=c++  /usr/bin/make arm.release vfp2=off vfp3=on hardfp=on ARFLAGS.target=crs werror=no
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=arm \
                  -S.arm  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=false -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3 -Dwerror='' -Dv8_use_arm_eabi_hardfloat=true
  CXX(target) /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
In file included from ../src/allocation.cc:33:
../src/utils.h:33:10: fatal error: 'climits' file not found
#include <climits>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o] Error 1
make: *** [arm.release] Error 2
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/libv8-3.16.14.19/gem_make.out


❯ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8
Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.19
Parsing documentation for libv8-3.16.14.19
Installing ri documentation for libv8-3.16.14.19
Done installing documentation for libv8 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed


❯ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20210120-6195-ojni3j.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
    from /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out


❯ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/v8
Building native extensions with: '--with-v8-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/v8'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20210120-6214-10f7ru2.rb extconf.rb --with-v8-dir\=/opt/homebrew/opt/v8
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
    from /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out


❯ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/v8/libexec/
Building native extensions with: '--with-v8-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/v8/libexec/'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20210120-6235-1hlxxtd.rb extconf.rb --with-v8-dir\=/opt/homebrew/opt/v8/libexec/
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
    from /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/vaibhavgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm exactly at the same point as you... (After the nightmare of installing Ruby, FFI, etc) ...  In some post I read about someone trying theminiracer gem instead.  If you are able to solve it please update your post xD

Comment: @Vaibhav Gupta [Here](https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/868b64cd60ab2d51ab24e7bf384da1ca) you can found your solution to [install](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1691#issuecomment-753636901)  therubyracer and libv8 in M1.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

- Ruby version: `2.6.1`
- OS version: `macOS Big Sur 11.2`

1. Install HomeBrew using Rosetta Termina
   https://5balloons.info/correct-way-to-install-and-use-homebrew-on-m1-macs/
2. 

```
    brew install v8@3.15
    gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8
    gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
```

Comment: Just a reminder, check if your v8 formula is in the correct directory. For me it was;  gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/homebrew/opt/v8@3.15

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by installing V8 on Rosseta 2 as V8 not yet supported for ARM.

You can try this

> gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' --
> --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15

Or install V8 on Rosseta 2.

Update: How to install ruby in x86_64 for M1.

1. Install homebrew in x86_64. Please refer to this guide [How to install ruby on m1](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/a-rubyist-s-apple-m1-review)
2. Install ASDF using x86_64
3. Install all other dependencies on x86_64 only such as postgres, redis, and V8 using x86_64 only.

Comment: The this is that v8@3.15 cant be installed via Rosseta.
Or at least there is no brew bottle for M1.

If you compile it within x86_64, You would need a x86_64 version of Ruby, which also have problems with M1

Comment: Yes, I had to install ruby within x86_64 for this.

Comment: How do you install Ruby ?
Did you use RVM? RBENV ? ASDF ? 

I'm having hard time installing Ruby within x86_64. 
Can you explain the process ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am had to install everything on x86_64 to make sure, I can work without any error. I work on rails 4.2.8. I am using M1 for my daily drive and didn't want to take much risk.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: I was having the same issue, this kinda solve my issue:

gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/Homebrew/opt/v8@3.15

Please see this link
https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/868b64cd60ab2d51ab24e7bf384da1ca#gistcomment-3698637

But now I am having a different issue when I rails s
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:

Comment: Yes indeed mine is all fixed, indeed follow that link from the answer. I had to remove rbenv and homebrew and started all from scratch.